# Different behaviour in Chrome and Chrome with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, ajax, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I noticed a different behaviour between Chrome and Chrome with Selenium webdriver.

I am trying to do some service virtualization, where a site is making a (cross domain) AJAX Post request with a custom header to another site.
This worked fine when running a Selenium test with Chrome webdriver, 
but when running manually with normal Chrome, the request method turns into "OPTIONS" according to Chrome dev tools,
the status code turns into "204 no content",
the custom header turns into "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: myCustomHeader" (so it is not set),
no body is sent and no javascript error is shown in the console.

When starting a Chrome instance with selenium, and manually playing the test steps, the request is sent correctly (correct method, custom header and body).

At first, I thought this was a cross-origin issue, so I tried starting chrome with "--disable-web-security" argument but this didn't change anything.
I also compared the settings found in "chrome://flags/" but they are identical.
Then I went into "Settings -> Advanced" and changed the normal Chrome to be the same as Chrome with webdriver. Also no luck there.
They are also both the same version.

The only difference I see now is that Chrome with webdriver displays the notice on the top "Chrome is beeing controlled by test software".

So I ran out of ideas, does anyone have another idea or experienced something similar?

**EDIT:**
Okay, I figured it out now. It actually was a cross-origin issue.
Chrome driver had the "--disable-web-security" capability set.

I had to start normal Chrome with "chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir" (in CMD) to get the same behaviour.